# Vetur says prop doesn't exist on type "never" when using a prop on template

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vetur

I am using Quasar framework with vue composition API and typescript on VSCode.

When trying to use a prop in the template, Vetur is giving me the error in the template `Property 'open' does not exist on type 'never'`

Source

```js
<template>
  <q-drawer v-model="open">
    test
  </q-drawer>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'AuthedLayout',
  props: {
    open: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  },
  components: {},
  setup() {}
});
</script>

<style></style>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. It was because I didn't have a `return` in the `setup` function. The error is misleading

Answer (score 0):

Please try below syntax with Quasar, i was facing the same issue with antd with vue.
v-model:value should work and it will sync with q-drawers v-model

```
  <q-drawer v-model:value="open">
    test
  </q-drawer>
```

Comment: it was because I forgot the `return` in `setup`. it was a vetur issue